# Pig: Pulling individual fields out after a GROUP

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In PigLatin, I want to pull the other fields out of a record I want to select because of an aggregate, such as `MAX`.

I'm having trouble explaining the problem, so here is an example. Let's say I want to grab the name of the oldest person at a household:

Relation `A` is four columns, `(name, address, zipcode, age)`

```
B = GROUP A BY (address, zipcode); # group by the address

# generate the address, the person's age, but how do I grab that person's name?
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group), MAX(age), ??? Name ???;
```

How do I generate the name of the person with the `MAX` age?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your logic is there can be more then 1 people with the MAX(age). Then you have to GROUP BY (name, address, age). But to give you a quick answer I will write that gets only one of the max ages. (I am not sure its the optimum way though)

```
C = FOREACH B {                          
   DA = ORDER A BY age DESC;                
   DB = LIMIT DA 1;                         
   GENERATE FLATTEN(group), FLATTEN(DB.age), FLATTEN(DB.name);
}
```

Comment: I can arbitrarily pick one if there is a tie. In my real data, the thing I am taking MAX will very rarely have a tie. Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll try it out

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with frail's answer which is accepted, as it would have undesirable behavior if the number in the LIMIT command is higher than 1. In particular, in that case the output would be a cross-product between all ages and names due to the last two FLATTEN calls. Then, if the value in the LIMIT is N, there would be N^2 output rows instead of intended N.

Much safer is to do the following in the GENERATE line, which would give exactly the same result as the accepted answer when 'LIMIT 1' is used:

```
GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (address, zipcode), FLATTEN(DB.(age, name)) AS (age, name);
```